# is it possible single document with double transaction at firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I am making todolist app. 
when I use transaction, I have a question.

I try to change todolist user count using transaction.
but It is became that user count is changed from each other two activity for some reason

So, this is that code

add user in todolist

```
val todoListRef = firestore!!.collection("todoList").document(intent.getStringExtra("checkList_name"))

firestore?.runTransaction { transaction ->
    var todoListDTO = transaction.get(todoListRef).toObject(TodoListDTO::class.java)
    if (todoListDTO == null) {
        todoListDTO = TodoListDTO()
        transaction.set(todoListRef, todoListDTO)
        return@runTransaction
    }

    if (!todoListDTO.todoListUsers.containsKey(currentUserUid!!)) {

        todoListDTO.todoListUserCount = todoListDTO.todoListUserCount + 1
        todoListDTO.todoListUsers[currentUserUid!!] = true
    }
    transaction.set(todoListRef, todoListDTO)
    return@runTransaction
}
```

remove user in todolist

```
val todoListRef = firestore!!.collection("todoList").document(checkListName!!)

firestore?.runTransaction { transaction ->
    val todoListDTO = transaction.get(todoListRef).toObject(TodoListDTO::class.java)
    todoListDTO!!.todoListUserCount = todoListDTO.todoListUserCount - 1
    todoListDTO.todoListUsers.remove(currentUserUid!!)
    transaction.set(todoListRef, todoListDTO)

    return@runTransaction
}
```

I'm worried about crash of transaction.
If someone is added todolist user count and at the same time the other someone is removed todolist user count, It cause transaction crush or not reflected the change.
Is it right? Or can I use double transaction with one document?

If it is problem, How can I change single document data without interrupting the transaction at each other activity?

Always Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore transactions are optimistic. In your transaction code you first *read* the document, then you determine the new value, and then you *write* the document. The Firestore client sends both the value it read *and* the new value to the server. The server then compares the value you read to the document it has, and only writes your new value if the document was unmodified during your transaction.

All this means is that there's no way for a document to be overwritten incorrectly if all client are using transactions. If you're seeing an incorrect write, you might want to check if you're not using a transaction somewhere.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm glad it wasn't a problem.